# Download file from Website using c# daily basis

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, download

I know there is a lot of existing post in this website about my subject and already read some of them but not answering my question in general.

Pretty simple: I want a solution which will allow me to download a file from a website with this constraint :

- Before to download the file, I need to specify a start and End date into two textbox, so I can't use an URL directly as this URL will change all the time.
- This file need to be downloaded 4 time per day, and without any human interaction.

So the best will be to have something like a scrpit and , for example, using windows scheduler, this script is executing at a specific time and download the file.

My question is: what is the best techno with c# to use for that?
I don't have a lot of experience with c#... From what I read Selenium Framework is good for WebDriven. Could I use that and automate the download?
Because from what I read, the user need to run his project but it can be automated like a script... Am I right?

Or do know another way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this as I don't have C# on my work machine, but I think it will be something like this.

Here is an example that covers these options:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
Uri ur = new Uri(http://remotehost.do/images/" + yesterday + "to" + tomorrow + "/excel.xls");
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClientDownloadProgressChanged;
client.DownloadDataCompleted += WebClientDownloadCompleted;
client.DownloadFileAsync(ur, @"C:\path\excel.xls");
```

And the callback's functions implemented as follows:

```
void WebClientDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download status: {0}%.", e.ProgressPercentage);
}

void WebClientDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download finished!");
}
```